# C code injection

Tags: c, static-analysis, code-injection

What I am trying to do seems simple comparing to complicated code static analysis work

1. finding all the assign code, and insert a new code snippet based on the value used in the assign code to update certain memory
2. finding all the basic control block, assign a unique id to each block, and insert a new code snippet based on the id to update certain memory

Currently I have the source code, so I don't need to deal with binary:)

But I am newly in this area and I am wondering if I need something like Perl script to analyse by hand..? Could any body give me some instructions about how to get this job done..?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "What I am trying to do seems simple" - well, no. You'll need a complete C parser for that. And a compiler you can extend to inject code.

Comment: Hi Mat, thank you and sorry for my immature saying... But I think I can just insert certain code snippet to the source code to get a "new" source code and put it in the regular compiler...Does it look more feasible..?

Comment: You still need a complete C parser/analyzer, and in that case figure out a way to do a proper "textual" change for your needs. That might actually be more difficult in the general case than working inside the compiler that is built with modularity/extensibility in mind (look at clang/llvm).

Comment: Antler has some pretty nice language "pattern matching" abilities without having to do a full parser. It's primarily a java tool, they used to have a C backend but I think that went away with the new version though. http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: What OP needs is a "program transformation tool".  Perl will not do satisfactorily.  I'd add a link to such tools, but SO zealots hate answers that mention tools.   If you want more details, you can check my bio.

Comment: @Mat Hi Mat, thank you a lot and finally I use Clang to do a source 2 source transformation:) Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe dynamic injection is easier in this case. Check pintool (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool). As far as I remember it allows tracing of memory operations (assignment is just on of the cases) and likely allows identification of basic blocks, but I am not sure, I have not done this kind of task with pin.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you, I think of pintool and finally I use Clang to achieve my goal! Wish you all the best!